# Removing leading and trailing zeros and have the result in two decimal places

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wanted to remove both leading and trailing zeros, and want to have the result in two decimal places. For example: if the number is 0.01, I want to see .01; if the number is 0.010, I want to see .01; if the number is 0.10, I want to see .10; if the number is 1, I want to see 1.00.

I would use a `FORMAT` function. 
For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT (0.090, '#.######')
```

works fine that it displays .09

However, when I use the same statement for a value greater than 1, it doesn't show the decimal places.

For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT (10, '#.######')
```

gives 10 while I'm expecting 10.00

I tried to use a `CASE` statement to solve this in vain. A case statement works fine for a value more than 1, but it doesn't remove the leading zeros.

```
DECLARE @a float = 10
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN @a <1 THEN  format (@a, '#.######') 
    ELSE CAST(FORMAT(@a, '#.######') AS money) 
END
```

gives 10.00 as I expect. However, when the value of @a is 0.090 for example, it gives 0.09 while I expect .09

Is there any way I can remove both trailing and leading zeros and have the result in two decimal places? Any guide is much appreciated.

Comment: Formatting is the responsibility of the _display_ layer. My recommendation is to return the raw data in SQL and configure the display (form, web page, report, etc.) to show the numbers however you want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with D Stanley that 'Formatting is the responsibility of the display layer', I know sometimes you need some dirty functions to be used inside stored procedures or other functions. Try with this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.toStr(@a float)  
RETURNS varchar(12)
AS 
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @ret varchar(12)
  SELECT @ret =
   CASE 
    WHEN @a < 1 THEN replace(format(@a, '.##'), '0.','.')
    ELSE FORMAT(@a, '#.00')
   END 
  RETURN @ret 
END;
```

I have tested with the following values:

```
select dbo.toStr(0.090);  -- .09
select dbo.toStr(1.09);   -- 1.09
select dbo.toStr(10.00);  -- 10.00
select dbo.toStr(1.2);    -- 1.20
```

Comment: Thanks. I've slightly modified .## to .###### as it cuts bigger numbers.